# populating a div from another select box which is populated using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am making a webpage that is having two select boxes of which one is to be populated using `ajax`. I am able to populate select box two using the value of select box one using `ajax`. But I am not able to populate a div  using the current value of second.

This is what I have done so far.

```
<tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td><select name="selProduct" id="selProduct"  onchange='loadXMLDoc();' >
            <option value="-1"> Select Product</option>
            <option value="0"> JSA Three Wheelers</option>
            <option value="1"> Rotavators</option>
            <option value="2"> ACE Tractors</option>
            <option value="3"> BCS Reaper Binder</option>
            <option value="4"> Lubi Pumps</option>
            <option value="5"> New Golden Punjab Thresers</option>

          </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>
            <div id="myDiv">
            <select name="selModel" id="selModel" onchange='loadXMLDoc1();'> 

            <option  value="-1">select Model</option>
            </select>
            </div>



        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
         <div id="divRate">

         </div>
        </td></tr>
```

I am able to populate the `selModel` select box using the function `loadXMLDoc()`. Now I want to fetch price of the model selected from `selModel` using function `loadXMLDoc1()` .
Here are the functions.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
 {
  function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}
  var sel=byId('selProduct');
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  { 
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","NewFile.jsp?str="+sel.value,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

}

```
function loadXMLDoc1()
{
 function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}
 var selModel=byId('selModel');
 var selProduct=byId('selProduct');

 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("divRate").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","selPrice.jsp?selProduct="+selProduct.value+"selModel="+selModel.value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

The file `selPrice.jsp` is as

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String selModel= request.getParameter("selModel");
String selProduct= request.getParameter("selProduct");
int valProduct= Integer.parseInt(selProduct);
int valModel= Integer.parseInt(selModel);
%>

<%if(valProduct ==0 && valModel==1 ){ %>
 <input type="text" value="173000" readonly="readonly">
<%} 
else if(valProduct ==0 && valModel==2 ){ %>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="183000">
<%}
else if (valProduct==1 && valModel==1){%>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="400000" >


<%} 
else if (valProduct==1 && valModel==2){%>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="450000">

<%} %>


</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get `loadXMLDoc1()` function fired `onchange` event of the second select box after the list gets populated using ajax.
Please guide me through this.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried registering the onchange right after populating the second list? document.getElementById('selModel').onChange = loadXMLDoc1; Not sure if that's the problem but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working...

**Sample javascript**

```
function loadXMLDoc() {   
document.getElementById("selModel").innerHTML = '<option value="A">A</option value="B">B<option value="C">C</option><option value="D">D</option>';
}

function loadXMLDoc1() {
    document.getElementById("divRate").innerHTML = document.getElementById("selModel").value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qL36s37a/

If this is not working still better you go with jQuery and use .live() or .on() method using which you can fire events on the elements that got embedded dynamically.